# How to connect a list box (MULTI SELECT) on form to connect/display to another sheet in workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, xlsm

I am trying to create a form:

[image: my form]

where you are able to select multiple items and it display in excel sheet

[image: "database ws"]

I was able to do so for selecting only one item in a list, but when changed to multi select I don't know how to link the form and the worksheet together.

Also - how do I make it display in the "database" portion of my form here:

[image: my form]

code for Module 1

```
Option Explicit
Sub Reset()

    Dim iRow As Long

    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] ' identifying the last row
    
    With frmForm
        .txtName.Value = ""
        .txtAge.Value = "'"
        
        .lstInvited.Clear
        
        .lstInvited.AddItem "Aya"
        .lstInvited.AddItem "Bi"
        .lstInvited.AddItem "Britt"
        .lstInvited.AddItem "Cami"
        .lstInvited.AddItem "Sarl"
        .lstInvited.AddItem  "Ch"
        
        
        
        .cmbTeacher.Clear
        
        .cmbTeacher.AddItem "A"
        .cmbTeacher.AddItem "Bia"
        .cmbTeacher.AddItem "Cami"
        .cmbTeacher.AddItem "China"

        
        
        
        .cmbStudy.Clear
        
        .cmbStudy.AddItem "1"
        .cmbStudy.AddItem "2"
        .cmbStudy.AddItem "3"
        .cmbStudy.AddItem "45"

        
        
        .lstAction.Clear
        
        
        .lstAction.AddItem "Wants to study again"
        .lstAction.AddItem "Other, Please specify in Notes"
    
        
        .lstInfo.Clear
        
        .lstInfo.AddItem "Open-minded"
        .lstInfo.AddItem "Needs to study in a different language"
        .lstInfo.AddItem "Other, Please specify in Notes"
        
        .lstZoom.Clear
        
        .lstZoom.AddItem "Attentive"
        .lstZoom.AddItem "Not interactive/ Not connected"
        .lstZoom.AddItem "Occupied"
        .lstZoom.AddItem "Other, Please specify in Notes"
        
        .txtNotes.Value = ""
        
        .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 10
        .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
        
        If iRow > 1 Then
            
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:J" & iRow
        Else
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:J2"
            
        End If
            
            
    End With
    

End Sub


Sub Submit()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    
    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] + 1
    
    
    With sh
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = frmForm.txtName.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.lstInvited.Value
        

        .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtAge.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.cmbTeacher.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.cmbStudy.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 6) = frmForm.dtpDate.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.lstAction.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 8) = frmForm.lstInfo.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 9) = frmForm.lstZoom.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 10) = frmForm.txtNotes.Value
    
    End With
    
End Sub


Sub Show_Form()

    frmForm.Show
    
End Sub
`



and then here is the code for form (frmForm)

        Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
        Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
        msgValue = MsgBox(" Do you want to reset the form?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
        If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        Call Reset
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
        Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
        msgValue = MsgBox(" Do you want to save the data?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
        If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        Call Submit
        Call Reset
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstInvited_Initialize()
        Me.lstInvited.RowSource = strInvitedList
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstAction_Initialize()
       Me.lstAction.RowSource = strDVActionList
    End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub lstAction_Click()
    For i = 0 To lstAction.ListCount - 1

    If lstAction.Selected(i) = True Then
     ListBox2.AddItem
     ListBox2.Column(0, (ListBox2.ListCount - 1)) = ListBox1.Column(0, i)
     ListBox2.Column(1, (ListBox2.ListCount - 1)) = ListBox1.Column(1, i)
     ListBox2.Column(2, (ListBox2.ListCount - 1)) = ListBox1.Column(2, i)

    End If

Next
End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Call Reset
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the list box. You can use the `.ListCount` property to get the number of rows (the index starts at 0 so use `.ListCount - 1`). You can check if the index is selected by using `.Selected(i)` where i is the loop counter.

So if your listbox is called ListBox1 you can do something like this to determine what rows are selected:

```
For i = 0 to ListBox1.Count - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then Debug.Print "Index " & i & " is selected"
Next i
```

Instead of the debug message you can add the information to your worksheet by using the listbox `.List` method, you'll need to use `i` for the row parameter and whatever number you need for the column parameter.

To add the information to the form you can use the `.List` method again to set those properties.

You may also want to look into assigning the values to an array as this would shorten your code.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! how would i add the information to the worksheet by using the listbox '.List' method, and using  i for the row parameter & column parameter.

Comment: where Would I put the code for this as well? the submit/save button?'For i = 0 to ListBox1.Count - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then Debug.Print "Index " & i & " is selected"
Next i'

Comment: The `.List` method takes one or two parameters. The first (pvargIndex) refers to the row of the list box starting at 0 and going to `.ListCount - 1` while the second (pvargColumn) starts at 0 and goes to `.ColumnCount - 1`. So you can get the information for each row by using the loop I provided and instead of printing a debug message, use `.List(i,<column index>)` to get each value and assign to the relevant area of the worksheet. As for where to put the code that depends on what you prefer but from my understanding the save button makes sense.